# How to add dependency java files while generating Bazel build with Thrift file

Tags: java, code-generation, thrift, bazel

I am trying to generate a jar using bazel build which will use thrift file. 
When I run bazel build ,It is creating a jar with thrift auto generated code. But I want to include some java files (client code -main class , one java class) to that jar while bazel build.
Below is the thrift file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
load("//tools/bzl:genthrift.bzl", "thrift_java_library")
thrift_java_library(
   name = "thriftbazelclient",
   srcs = ["spell.thrift"],

)
```

How to add main_class and deps ?

It is not taking main_class as there is no attribute main_class def thrift_java_library in genthrift.bzl

Thanks,

Comment: What thrift rules do you use?

Comment: I am using thrift_java_library , the jar file which is generated contains only thrift auto generated code. I want to include my java files as part of jar file

Comment: These? https://github.com/wt/bazel_thrift

Comment: I have a java main class ,I want to include that into the jar

Answer (score 1):

Create a new target using `java_binary` that depends on the thrift library, e.g.:

```
java_binary(
    name = "my_thrift",
    srcs = glob(["src/*.java"]),
    main_class = "com.example.MyThrift",
    deps = [ ":thriftbazelclient" ],
)
```

And build a deploy jar (jar that contains all transitive dependencies), e.g.:

`bazel build //:my_thrift_deploy.jar`

You can follow the [Bazel Java Tutorial](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/tutorial/java.html) to get all the details right.